# php artisan storage:link works differently in local and in prod

Tags: php, laravel, storage

I am uploading a pic following the [laravel doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/filesystem#the-public-disk)

```
$file = request()
        ->file('file')
        ->store('images/avatar', 'public');
```

Now I have the file uploaded in  : `storage/app/public/images/avatar/ICZWltwuuKQwsD0Valdf7oONdpKNjhugBxMcHSen.jpeg`

As stated in docs, I do

```
php artisan storage:link
```

to make a symbolic link between `storage` and `public`

now, when I go to public folder, I have a `storage` folder link --> /Users/myuser/Documents/Proyectos/laravel/storage/app/public

So, in local, 
`https://laravel.dev/images/avatar/ICZWltwuuKQwsD0Valdf7oONdpKNjhugBxMcHSen.jpeg` works

but with my production server, I myst use URL :

`https://laravel.dev/storage/images/avatar/ICZWltwuuKQwsD0Valdf7oONdpKNjhugBxMcHSen.jpeg`

Any idea why is this happening????

Comment: I don't know the reason behind that, but maybe you  can use an URL rewrite to fix that

Comment: well, both works with storage/ inside URL, so really, I could add it to url, but I would like to know why is the behaviour different...

Comment: have you executed the command on the production server? and how you are accessing files docs says echo asset('storage/file.txt') ?

Comment: Yes, I executed the command on production server. I use it like you mention, but I still don't understand why it is working without "storage/" in local.

Comment: I guess it is because you are in production.... a quick check might be to just switch your production server application from production to local and checking for URL (change .env setting APP_ENV from production to local)...